# how can I teach pytesseract what it should be recognizing with exemples to make it more accurate?

Tags: python, automation, python-tesseract

I need to read text from a images with pytesseract, and I'm able to do it most of the time using [one of my older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75203086/how-to-read-numbers-on-screen-efficiently-pytesseract). Now the problem is that pytesseract has a really hard time reading big numbers, 0 and special characers like €, $ or ₽

[image: 5 311 111 ₽] [image: 4 000 000 ₽] [image: 209 $]

Pytesseract often delete 0s (so 4 000 000 is red as 4 or 4 000), delete some too much repetitive character (5 311 111 is red as 531 111), read $ as 8 or 5 and ₽ as 2 and thus even with differrent thresholding. Is there no way to teach pytesseract what should be read as a 0 or a 8 and what should not using images exemples ?

my code :

```py
def read_image(tresh, path, img, show=False) : #path and img has to be strings
    originalImage = cv2.imread(path+"\\"+img)
    grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(originalImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (_, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, tresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) #thresh goes from 110 to 125 to test different thresholding, 121 to 125 often works better
    text = pyt.image_to_string(blackAndWhiteImage, config="--psm 7 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789")
    string = str(text).replace("\n", "")
    return string
```